# Sort array of points in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I got an array of points declared like this:

```
found = np.empty(img_rgb.shape[:2])
```

It represents values from OpenCV template matching.
As I kept only the points that had desired values from the matching, I've rewritten it before iterating:

```
found2 = np.where(found)
```

Now I iterate through it like this:

```
for pt in zip(*found2[::-1]):
    (x, y) = pt
```

But how do I sort it so it would iterate from the lowest to highest value in `found[x][y]` array?

I tried `np.argsort()` but doesn't seem to keep a proper x,y indexes. In fact it doesn't sort by values at all I guess.

EDIT: To be clear:

```
img_rgb = cv2.imread(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'some.png'))

(...)

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, tmpl, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
loc = np.where(res > 230000)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
   (x, y) = pt
   found[y][x] = -res[y][x]
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? `np.where()` *does* sort the elements, by row, then column. So, I'm not sure what the goal here is. Edit: ah, wait so you want to order by the template matching image *values*. Is that correct? My original question still stands on *why* you'd want to do this as this seems extremely slow for no reason. Do you actually need *every* pixel? Or just some subset?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work slow. I need a subset of found values greater than threshold. Then sort them by value. Then iterate through it. I'm not really the best in Python :(

Comment: (a)Is `found` a 2d array of bools ? (b) By `found[x][y]`, do you actually mean `found[x,y]`? **(c)** What do you mean by "lowest to highest value in `found[x][y]`, especially if `found` has only bools?

Comment: `found[x][y]` has value, that can be a bigint, from `cv2.matchTemplate()`

Comment: Your "EDIT to be clear" seems to make it even less clear. It introduces `loc`, and your statement of requirement doesn't mention `loc` at all

Comment: And what are you doing with the sorted values? The reason I'm asking is there may be a better way to achieve what you want without sorting said values and using some functions directly.

Comment: `loc` is only a selected threshold above some value

Comment: Also, what should the sort order be if there's a tie? Does it matter?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I need to mark found patters on the image, but so they wouldn't cross eachother, so want to start drawing from the most accurate one. Sort order doesn't matter. I added `-` to value so it would sort the right way.

Comment: You said you wanted it sorted min to max, but you want it the other way IIUC. The best matches first.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds yes, that's why `found[y][x] = -res[y][x]` <--- negative, so would order from lowest to highest still be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand you correctly, but do you want something like:

```
found = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 4))
found2 = np.where(found)
found
# array([[5, 6, 8, 6],
#        [0, 7, 7, 3],
#        [7, 6, 0, 5]])
found2
# (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3]))

order = found[found2].argsort()
x, y = found2[1][order], found2[0][order]
found[y, x]
# array([3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8])
```

This sorts the 2d indices in `found2` by the values at the points in `found` they reference.

Comment: I edited my question to point out what is `found`, I still need the iteration code, as I iterate through `found2`, not `found`, but maybe I understand it wrong

Comment: @FlashThunder `(y, x)` is the same as `found2` only reordered. You can assign it back `found2 = y, x` and use your loop unchanged.

Comment: @FlashThunder Sorry, I don't understand the question. Once you have defined `found2` in your code you insert the line starting with `order =` and the next line and the line I wrote in my last comment `found2 = y, x` and that should be all you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

```py
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, tmpl, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
count = np.sum(res > 230000)
y, x = np.unravel_index((-res).argsort(None), res.shape)
for row, col in zip(y[:count], x[:count]):
    print(res[row, col], (row, col))
```

---

Explanation for each line:

```
count = np.sum(res > 230000)
```

gets the total number of values you want to iterate over.

```
y, x = np.unravel_index((-res).argsort(None), res.shape)
```

Here, `argsort(None)` will return the linear indices into the array which sorts it. We want the (row, column) indices though, not linear ones, so we use `np.unravel_index()` to get 2d indices out. Using the negative of the result to sort from max to min, like you did in the OP.

Then finally, we can iterate through the points:

```
for row, col in zip(y[:count], x[:count]):
    print(res[row, col], (row, col))
```

Printing is just to show indeed we are getting the highest values first, and showing the (row, column) index for those corresponding values.

---

Example:

```py
>>> import cv2
>>> import numpy as np
>>> img = np.uint8(255*np.random.rand(100, 100))
>>> tmp = np.uint8(255*np.random.rand(10, 10))
>>> res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, tmp, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
>>> count = np.sum(res > 100000)
>>> y, x = np.unravel_index((-res).argsort(None), res.shape)
>>> for row, col in zip(y[:count], x[:count]):
>>>     print(res[row, col], (row, col))
206337.11 (19, 12)
177079.31 (76, 9)
173258.67 (63, 15)
...
100202.44 (56, 1)
100098.41 (0, 48)
100089.09 (68, 47)
```

---

Note that these final values are in (row, column) order, that is, opposite from (x, y) point order, so feel free to swap as needed.

Comment: thanx! that explained a lot

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
sorted_pts = sorted(zip(*loc), key=lambda t:res[t])
print (sorted_pts)
```

**Try it out with sample data:**

Let's take some sample data on a smaller scale (taking `res` as just a shape `(3,4)` array, and `4` as the `threshold`):

```
import numpy as np

res = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
print (res)

loc = np.where(res > 4)  # Dummy threshold == 4

sorted_pts = sorted(zip(*loc), key=lambda t:res[t[0],t[1]])
print (sorted_pts)
```

**Output:**

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]   # res
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
# sorted_pts
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)]
```

**Note:**
(Verifying that the points are sorted according to the values in `res`)

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)]
   |       |       |        |       |       |       |
   |       |       |        |       |       |       |
   V       V       V        V       V       V       V
   5       6       7        8       9       10      11
```

Comment: sorry for not accepting that, but I can't accept two answers, was a nice answer tho'! thank you!